How to Implement Ternary Conditional in a Racket Language Interpreter with Structs?
I’m working on an interpreter for a simple language in Racket, and I need to implement a ternary conditional (Expr ? Expr : Expr) similar to JavaScript. My language supports basic operations like addition, subtraction, and equality, and now I’m adding booleans and this ternary operation.
here is my current code for parse
;; parse: Expr -> AST
;; Parses “custom Lang” Expr to AST
(define (parse expr)
  (match expr
    [(? number?) (num expr)]                      
    [(? string?) (str expr)]                      
    ['TRUE (bool #t)]                            
    ['FALSE (bool #f)]                           
    [`(+ ,x ,y) (add (parse x) (parse y))]        
    [`(- ,x ,y) (sub (parse x) (parse y))]       
    [`(=== ,x ,y) (equals (parse x) (parse y))]  
    [`(,test '? ,true ': ,false)                 
     (condt (parse test) (parse true) (parse false))]
    [_ (error "Invalid custom Lang expression")]))

Im learning racket atm, and I only have previous java experience. im assuming this is like the class in java, and im defining what can be parsed?
and then I would have a run fn that takes parsed input and output results.
here is my run
;; run: AST -> Result
;; Computes the result of running a customLang AST
(define (run ast)
  (match ast
    [(num n) n]
    [(str s) s]
    [(bool b) b]
    [(add x y) (cus+ (run x) (run y))]
    [(sub x y) (cus- (run x) (run y))]
    [(equals x y) (equal? (run x) (run y))]
    [(condt test true-branch false-branch)
     (if (truthy? (run test)) (run true-branch) (run false-branch))]
    [_ NaN]))


so I understood this as if true run 1st, if false run 2nd. and my parse seem to have correct setup. but when I try to run the tests
   ;; JS "truthy" true
   (check-equal? (evalcustom '(10 ? 100 : 200)) 100)

   ;; JS "truthy" false
   (check-equal? (evalcustom '((- 100 100) ? "a" : "b")) "b")))

it could not recognize and just outputs my error msg that I created.
Im confused on how to make this structure and AST tree thing worked together and why they should work. therefore I could not figure out how to debug my issue.
thanks for help I really appreciate it.

No, it's not like a class in Java - it's a procedure (or function). Very little in Racket is like anything in Java. You need to learn Racket "from scratch", or you will get very frustrated very quickly.

You have an extra level of quotes in the pattern.
[`(,test '? ,true ': ,false)                 
     (condt (parse test) (parse true) (parse false))]

should be
[`(,test ? ,true : ,false)                 
     (condt (parse test) (parse true) (parse false))]

to match the list you're providing; the current pattern would need '(10 '? 100 ': 200) in order to match.

I feel like this has come up before and there's a duplicate but I couldn't find one with some searching.
